# How to use listview to populate a table layout

Tags: android, arrays, listview, tablelayout

I have the following code from the Bluetooth chat example. All I am looking to do is take the data in over bluetooth and display it as strings in the right place constantly in the table layout. Thanks to the BT example most of it is done for me, but changing the layout in the main file has not worked. Am I taking the right approach, or do I need to make a whole new adapter to handle my data and layout requirements? The way I understand the code, the data is being put into an array with the R.layout.message format and then the R.id.in is telling the program how to display the info. Do I need a separate field ID for each cell I want to display the data from the array in? I appreciate any help you can give me.

```
 // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
    mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
    mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
    mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);
```

From the layout.message file

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#A4C639"
android:textSize="18sp"
```

/>

From the layout.main file

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1,2">

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="RPM"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <TextView
         android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Gear"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="24sp"
         />
          <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Temp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
</TableRow>
   <TableRow>

     <ListView android:id="@+id/in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
           <ListView android:id="@+id/in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

```
<TableRow>

    <TextView
         android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="MPH"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
          <ListView android:id="@+id/in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Battery Voltage"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
```

```
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="right"
         android:padding="3dip" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
         <ListView android:id="@+id/in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
         </TableRow>
```

```
<!--   
<ListView android:id="@+id/in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send"
    />
</LinearLayout>
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with the [ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). Since you are using complicated views as rows, you will eventually need to override the `getView` method on your `ArrayAdapter` to inflate the row layout and set its views appropriately.

Comment: I looked at the tutorial, but I cannot really figure out what you are talking about. Is it possible to use an array of data with each object in the array being represented by a textview? I do not want a list for each item in my UI, just to display one object in the array at a time in the correct location.

Comment: Yes, a ListView (or any AdapterView) will read one item from your data structure for each row.